# Система обновлений Android приложения

Tags: android, обновление

Здравствуйте

Как реализовать обновления приложения на Android?
К примеру, приложение 1.0 через пол года обновилось до версии 1.5. Как можно сделать так чтобы при согласии пользователя скачивалась новая версия приложения и сама обновлялась ?

Спасибо!

Comment: очень странный велосипед

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пользуйтесь [play.google.com](http://play.google.com) и не придумывайте.

Но если сильно хочется извращений - то никто не мешает поднять свой http сервер (хоть на narod.ru) и хранить там специальный файл (например "http://mysyte.com/last.txt"). Клиент скачивает этот файл время от времени с помощью [httpClient](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) и считывает с него последнюю версию (как оно там будет храниться - сами придумывайте). Если текущая версия отличается от последней, просто запускаете браузер с указанием url на apk (спросив пользователя конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Если очень хочется, можете почитать здесь:
[Пишем свой Android Market](http://habrahabr.ru/post/163397/).